# Better approach for python dictionary problem

Tags: python

here is Sample Data. Everything in input directory is dynamic. Only thing is data dictionary will have fix 7 different values for each value of keys in input_dict. And it may have only 1 or 0 values.

```
input_dict = { 'all_val' : ['a', 'b', 'c' ],
               '2nd_group' : ['a', 'b'] ,
               '3rd_grp' : ['a' , 'c']}
data = {  
'a' :      [1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
'b' :      [0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
'c' :      [0,1,1,0,0,0,1]    }

required_output = {'2nd_group': 5, '3rd_grp': 4, 'all_val': 6}
```

logic: for all_val, take a , b and c and go to data dictionary. if either of a[0],b[0],c[0] is 1 then should consider 1. same way for a[1],b[1],c[1] ... and finally count of all 1s.

My solution:

```
temp_dict = {}
output_dict = {}

for a in input_dict.keys():
    temp_dict[a] = [0]*7

for key, value in input_dict.items():
    for v in value:
        for j , d in enumerate(data[v]):
            temp_dict[key][j] = max( temp_dict[key][j] , d  )

for k,v in temp_dict.items():
    total = 0
    for t in temp_dict[k]:
        total = total + t
    output_dict[k] = total

print output_dict
```

Is there any way to improve performance or any other approach for this problem.

Comment: you can always reduce the amount of code, and write it all in one step like this: `print({k: sum(max(data[key][index] for key in keys) for index in range(7)) for k, keys in input_dict.items()})`,  but I'm not sure it's more readable. There are some parts that can be simplified, like the search for max value across a, b, and c, or the sum at the end.

Comment: If data dictionary is just containing 7 bits, the representation as a list of 7 elements is ambitious - why not use and integer and work with bit masks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a few tweaks and simplify the logic.For example, You do not need to create the keys separately in your first pass. You can skip over the temp dict in the second pass. The overall logic can be simplified.

```
input_dict = { 'all_val' : ['a', 'b', 'c' ],
               '2nd_group' : ['a', 'b'] ,
               '3rd_grp' : ['a' , 'c']}
data = {  
'a' :      [1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
'b' :      [0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
'c' :      [0,1,1,0,0,0,1]    }

#required_output = {'2nd_group': 5, '3rd_grp': 4, 'all_val': 6}
res = {} 
for key,value in input_dict.items():
    output = 0
    #create a zip from the lists in data so you can check for 1s at every index
    for i in zip(*[data[v] for v in value]): 
        if any(i): #checking if any of them have a 1. 
            output += 1
    res[key] = output
```

timeit results:

New code:`6.36 µs ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Code in question (base benchmark):`19.8 µs ± 339 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: for curiosity, why you added * in zip(*[data[v] for v in value]) line?  what it does exactly.

Comment: That's the part that unpacks the list of 3 (or however many/few) lists so that you can zip them properly. zip expects the lists like zip(list1,list2,list3) but we do not know how many lists we will need beforehand as it is not constant. zip([list1,list2,list3]) doesn't do anything for you. Hence the little star. @PallavPatel

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_dict = { 'all_val' : ['a', 'b', 'c' ],
               '2nd_group' : ['a', 'b'] ,
               '3rd_grp' : ['a' , 'c']}
data = {  
'a' :      [1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
'b' :      [0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
'c' :      [0,1,1,0,0,0,1]    }

# {'2nd_group': 5, '3rd_grp': 4, 'all_val': 6}

temp_dict = defaultdict(list)

SIZE_OF_LIST = 7

data_keys = data.keys()

# we're basically constructiing the temp_dict on the fly by iterating throug the X and Y axis of the matrix
for i in range(SIZE_OF_LIST):  # i is in X axis of the matrix and represents the columns in this case
    for group, group_items in input_dict.items():  # for each column we iterate over the Y axis (a, b, c)

        # we then need to obtain all the values on a column (the actual 0's and 1's) and create a
        # list from it. In this list we take only does rows that are of interest for us
        # For example, for 2nd_group (a, b), considering that we are on column 0 the resulting list
        # will be generated by getting the values for 'a' and 'b', hence we will have [1, 0]
        data_values = [data[data_key][i] for data_key in group_items]  # thanks to list comprehensions

        # we then need to evaluate the previously created list with the any
        # any(data_vaues) is actually any([1, 0]) (from the previous example)
        # which yelds 1, because there is at least one value with the value 1
        # the resulting value is added at the right position in the temp_dict
        temp_dict[group].append(1 if any(data_values) else 0)

output_dict = {}
for group, elements in temp_dict.items():
    # we just iterate over the temp_dict one more time and create the 
    # sums for all our groups (all_val, 2nd_group, 3rd_group)
    # and add up all the 1's in the list. 
    # For example if we're on '2nd_group' then it's basically a sum(temp_dict['2nd_group'])
    # which yields your desired result
    output_dict[group] = sum(elements)

print output_dict
```

Comment: you may consider adding comments and explanation as to what you improved and why

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, there are a few parts that can be simplified:

instead of

```
for k,v in temp_dict.items():
    total = 0
    for t in temp_dict[k]:
        total = total + t
    output_dict[k] = total
```

you can write:

```
output_dict = {k: sum(v) for k,v in temp_dict.items()}
```

Instead of

```
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    for v in value:
        for j , d in enumerate(data[v]):
            temp_dict[key][j] = max( temp_dict[key][j] , d  )
```

you can write:

```
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    temp_dict[key] = [max(data[v][index] for v in value) for index in range(7)]
```

Then you can consider combining everything and getting to:

```
output_dict = {k: sum(max(data[key][index] for key in keys) for index in range(7)) for k, keys in input_dict.items()}
```

Comment: [max(data[v][index] for v in value) for index in range(7)] -- is this comprehension or generator ? I am trying to run and understand this and looks like it is generator. Could you please explain this syntax bit more.

Comment: I think, I got it.. I replaced max and change parenthesis from ( )to [ ] and it gave me list of values of data dictionary. And max is used to find max result out of small sublists. please correct me if my understanding is not right.

Comment: `max(data[v][index] for v in value)` here the expression passed to `max` is a generator. `[max ... for index in range(7)]` this is a list comprehension (the `[]` are the clue here)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the OR logic operation as the following:

```
import numpy as np
output = {}
for key in input_dict:
    r = []
    for data_key in data:
        if data_key in input_dict[key]:
            if len(r) == 0:
                r = np.asarray(data[data_key])
            else:
                r = r | np.asarray(data[data_key])
    output[key] = list(r).count(1)
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach computes in parallel all items in the list with seven elements and does not require separate installed items as numpy. In Python 3 it reads:

```
import operator
import functools

input_dict = { 'all_val' : ['a', 'b', 'c' ],
               '2nd_group' : ['a', 'b'] ,
               '3rd_grp' : ['a' , 'c']}
data = {
    'a' : 0b1010001,
    'b' : 0b0011010,
    'c' : 0b0110001}

def num_bits(n):
    result = 0
    while n > 0:
        result += n & 1
        n >>= 1
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = {}
    for inkey, labels in input_dict.items():
        result[inkey] = num_bits(functools.reduce(operator.__or__, (data[l] for l in labels)))
    print(result)
```

Fully adventurous one could even replace the main part by a Dictionary comprehension:

```
print({inkey: num_bits(functools.reduce(operator.__or__, (data[l] for l in labels))) for inkey, labels in input_dict.items()})
```